# "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" for update statement from 'inner' set to 'update' set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, navision

Error

> 'The multi-part identifier "ar_update.Id" could not be bound.'

as line denoted in sql script.

I also tried other columns for the errant join to try to prompt different errors and gives same error results.

Why/How to qualify the 'inner' processing set back to the 'update' set?

```
update ar_update 
   set ar_update.[GLEntry_Amount] = ar_sum.[GLEntry_Amount_sum]
  from [dbo].[ASL_Result_VGO]  as ar_update  

  join (select  ar.[Id]                        as [Id]
               ,ar.[Company Id]                as [Company Id]
               ,ar.[Schedule Name]             as [Schedule Name]       
               ,ar.[Line No_]                  as [Line No_]            
               ,ar.[Row No_]                   as [Row No_]             
               ,ar.[Posting Date]              as [Posting Date]        
               ,ar.[Business Centre Code]      as [Business Centre Code]
               ,ar.[Site Locations Code]       as [Site Locations Code] 

               ,GLEntry_Amount_sum = 
                    (select  sum(are.[GLEntry_Amount])     
                     from    [dbo].[ASL_Result_VGO]  as are
                     where   are.[Company Id]           = ar.[Company Id]  and          
                             are.[Schedule Name]        = ar.[Schedule Name]  and       
                             are.[Posting Date]         = ar.[Posting Date]  and          
                             are.[Business Centre Code] = ar.[Business Centre Code]  and   
                             are.[Site Locations Code]  = ar.[Site Locations Code]  and 
                             are.[Row No_] in ( select * from dbo.udf_range_expand_VGO(ar.[Totaling]) )  
                    )

        from    [dbo].[ASL_Result_VGO]  as ar
        where   ar.[Id] = ar_update.[Id]    -- The multi-part identifier "ar_update.Id" could not be bound.  

       )  ar_sum  on  ar_update.[Id] = ar_sum.[Id]           

    where   ar_update.[Totaling Type] = 2  and   -- formulas
            len(trim(ar_update.[Totaling])) > 0  and      
            charindex('..', ar_update.[Totaling]) > 0   -- P ranges
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happened because on `where ar.[Id] = ar_update.[Id]` because `ar_update.[Id]` is not a value it is a multivalued type, it's like you were comparing a list with an integer, try this

```
update ar_update 
   set ar_update.[GLEntry_Amount] = ar_sum.[GLEntry_Amount_sum]
  from [dbo].[ASL_Result_VGO]  as ar_update  

  join (select  ar.[Id]                        as [Id]
               ,ar.[Company Id]                as [Company Id]
               ,ar.[Schedule Name]             as [Schedule Name]       
               ,ar.[Line No_]                  as [Line No_]            
               ,ar.[Row No_]                   as [Row No_]             
               ,ar.[Posting Date]              as [Posting Date]        
               ,ar.[Business Centre Code]      as [Business Centre Code]
               ,ar.[Site Locations Code]       as [Site Locations Code] 
               ,GLEntry_Amount_sum =     (select  sum(are.[GLEntry_Amount])     
                     from    [dbo].[ASL_Result_VGO]  as are
                     where   are.[Company Id]           = ar.[Company Id]  and          
                             are.[Schedule Name]        = ar.[Schedule Name]  and       
                             are.[Posting Date]         = ar.[Posting Date]  and          
                             are.[Business Centre Code] = ar.[Business Centre Code]  and   
                             are.[Site Locations Code]  = ar.[Site Locations Code]  and 
                             are.[Row No_] in ( select * from dbo.udf_range_expand_VGO(ar.[Totaling]) )  
                    )

        from    [dbo].[ASL_Result_VGO]  as ar
 

       )  ar_sum  on  ar_update.[Id] = ar_sum.[Id]           

    where   ar_update.[Totaling Type] = 2  and   -- formulas
            len(trim(ar_update.[Totaling])) > 0  and      
            charindex('..', ar_update.[Totaling]) > 0
```